# select end of month and make it a string in pyspark

Tags: date, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a loop in pyspark where I give a month and it should select the table on the end of the month and the end of month of the previous month.
The selection of the month is made with a string.
So I give '201901' and it should select '20190131' and '20181231'.

And if possible it should run automatically and select the end of previous month from today and end of previous previous month of today.
So today we are 2020-05-07 so it should select '20200430' and '20200331'.

```
def selectTables(date):

    i = 0

    for i in range(len(date)): 

        recentDate = .... # should be for the first iteration '20190131'
        previousDate = .... # should be for the first iteration '20181231'

    recent = spark.read.parquet('table.parquet/date=' + recentDate[i])
    previous = spark.read.parquet('table.parquet/date=' + previousDate[i])



selectTables(['201901', '201902'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`add_months`**,**`last_day`** in built spark functions to get last day.

**`Example:`**

```
date='201901'

recentDate=spark.sql("select string(last_day(to_date('{}','yyyyMM')))".format(date)).collect()[0][0]
#u'2019-01-31'

previousDate=spark.sql("select string(last_day(add_months(to_date('{}','yyyyMM'),'-1')))".format(date)).collect()[0][0]
#u'2018-12-31'
```

Comment: Okay and how do I change the format from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyyMMdd? It can be a string. It doesn't have to be a date.

Comment: the selection of date in the parquet file is with /date=20190131 which is a string and not a date like /date=2019-01-31